# The Longest -1 Word

Tags: word, optimization

What is the longest -1 word (or the word worth most in Scrabble for words with the same amount of letters (which is just the addition of all the letter values of the original 'word', no constraints)), where a -1 word is defined as:

- This 'word' does not have to be an actual word, just a string of letters.
- one can replace each and every letter in the 'word' with another letter to create a word that appears in the [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com) database.

An example of a -1 word would be "gub," and the replacements one could make would be "rub," "gob," and "gun."

Comment: Could you explain example more? For each word you calculate a number according to sum formula? what is this formula and how do you get -1 for gub?

Comment: @klm123 I think you misunderstand, '-1 word' is a title for a type of word defined as above

Comment: @klm123 I was confused at first as well, but it's just a string where you can replace any one of its characters and have it be an actual word afterwards

Comment: @DrunkWolf No, you need to be able to do that to every single letter - I'll change that.

Comment: @awesomepi that's what I implied with you can take 'any'

Comment: @DrunkWolf Yeah I know, that was my fault

Comment: Can we assume any placement on the Scrabble board we want? Can we use any length of word that we want? Are we limited to the actual set of Scrabble tiles (for repeated letters)? Do we get a 50 point bonus for every word if the length is 7+?

Comment: See, THIS is a good open-ended puzzle. It's actually well-constrained.

Comment: @user17625 the scrabble scoring only comes into play at equal length, so it's irrelevant

Comment: @DrunkWolf What is irrelevant? If we're placing the word on an actual Scrabble board then the spacing of high value letters matters. If we get the bingo bonus, then a 7+ letter word with fewer edit 1 distance words will likely beat an 6- letter word with many edit 1 distance words.

Comment: @user17625 the 7+ letter word bonus you only get once, seeing as you only give 1 word. And each 7+ letter word will get that bonus, so it's irrelevant. That said, i'm fairly sure the idea is that we look at the score with no board present.

Comment: @DrunkWolf My interpretation is that you're giving a set of words and getting their collective score, which would include 50 * number of words if the base is 7+ letters long. You have a different interpretation. Only the OP can confirm the intent of the puzzle.

Comment: The scrabble scoring is just the addition of all the letter values; there are no other constraints or conditions.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a 7-letter -1 word:

> **PASTERS** ([English word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pasters), score: 9)
>
>  [**M**ASTERS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masters)
>  [P**O**STERS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/posters)
>  [PA**T**TERS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patters)
>  [PAS**S**ERS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/passers)
>  [PAST**O**RS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pastors)
>  [PASTE**L**S](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pastels)
>  [PASTER**N**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pastern)

Comment: I was concerned that your word really was a word, but the rules do allow for that.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, let's get the ball rolling with a simple 5-letter word:

> **SLOPS**
>
> With the changed words being:
> **F**LOPS
> S**T**OPS
> SL**A**PS
> SLO**T**S
> SLOP**E**

Answer (score 6):

### 7 letters, score 13

There are no 8 to 15 letter solutions using SOWPODS. The best word which is valid with both SOWPODS and dictionary.com scores 13:

> POPPIES
>
>  KOPPIES
>  PAPPIES or PUPPIES
>  POTPIES
>  POPSIES
>  POPPLES
>  POPPITS
>  POPPIED

NB SOWPODS gives more options for some of the positions, but the above list is filtered against dictionary.com.

---

There is a 15-pointer in SOWPODS, but it isn't valid against dictionary.com:

> PICKIES
>
>  DICKIES, HICKIES, MICKIES, SICKIES, *BICKIES, *TICKIES, *WICKIES
>  POCKIES
>  PINKIES, *PISKIES
>  *PICCIES
>  PICKLES
>  *PICKINS
>  PICKIER

* Not in dictionary.com

There is only one other 7-letter answer, which Miles has already given.

---

### Bonus challenge

The highest scoring word is only 4 letters and scores 25. What is it?

> FUZZ
>
>  BUZZ
>  FIZZ
>  FUTZ
>  FUZE